# Wrap content and remove extra whitespace?

Tags: css

I'm having a dilemma which is causing my website to be pretty ugly, what I'm essentially trying to do is make these tiles wrap nicely and show more tiles on one row dependent on the client's screen size.

Most of it works but it looks terrible if aligned to the center (Tiles center)

**Text-align: center**
[image]

**Text-align: left**
[image]

**What I want it to look like:**
http://puu.sh/d3Rpt/6d1550eaa3.png

As you can see, the left align looks more aesthetically pleasing but there is a massively ugly piece of white space, what I want to do is remove that white space or center the actual tile parent.

```
 <div class='ioholder'>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="imghold">
                        <p>
                        Test
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

.ioholder
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;


    padding:10px;
}

.imghold
{
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:200px;
    width:200px;
    height:240px;
    max-height:240px;
    margin:4px;
    text-align:left;

    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgb(175,175,175);
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you posted the same picture twice.

Comment: I will double check, but if I remember right you need some JS to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for flex boxes. You can set different levels of importance to boxes so some will expand to fill blank space while others do not. There are a lot of excellent examples you can use to learn at css-tricks here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Brilliant, this method made the site look far better and even gives me larger boxes which scale perfectly to fill the whitespace, Correct answer found. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @stevob21 Please let me know how you accomplished this, a codepen would be useful, or a separate answer with the specific code. I am not able to understand which parts of the flex box to use to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve so I added this to the **CSS** based on my understanding:

```
.ioholder {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}

.ioholder > .imghold{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, still does exactly the same as the left align method with the massive piece of white space to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you tou use grid system, for example Yui3 Grid - http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssgrids/ - or some other grid system.

```css
.imghold{
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

.container{
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ioholder{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssgrids/cssgrids-min.css">

<div class='ioholder'>
<div class='yui3-g container'>
  <div class="yui3-u-1-6"><div class="imghold">one</div></div>
  <div class="yui3-u-1-6"><div class="imghold">two</div></div>
  <div class="yui3-u-1-6"><div class="imghold">three</div></div>
  <div class="yui3-u-1-6"><div class="imghold">four</div></div>
  <div class="yui3-u-1-6"><div class="imghold">five</div></div>
  <div class="yui3-u-1-6"><div class="imghold">six</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

You can also use responsive grid:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssgrids-responsive/cssgrids-responsive-min.css">
```

and then

```
<div class='yui3-g-r'>
<!- ... ->
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this method and it still aligns all the content to the left of the parent element. http://puu.sh/d3SQW/fd692b2e95.jpg

Comment: There is a problem with this, the tiles must be the exact size that has been listed but also show a different amount of tiles per row depending on the width of the user's screen. - This method just stretches the tiles.

Comment: Then this method is not for you. Consider: imagine 15 inch and 23 inch display. If you will have the tiles with fixed width, then this tiles will be very small on large displays (or big in small display). That's why we use % width. Bootstrap uses the same technique.

Comment: Marked as correct, this seems like the only method that is going to work reasonably.